# ASP.NET UpdatePanel flickers on partial postbacks in IE11 on Windows 10, when it has scrollable div

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

UpdatePanel flickers when the user clicks a button that causes a partial postback, when button positioned inside scrollable div element inside that updatepanel (when a div without scrolling does not flicker).  Flicker becomes stronger as the number of elements inside a div increases. The question is how to remove flicker.

This issue appear only in IE11 under Windows 10. In other browsers the problem does not recur, even in IE11 under Windows 8.1 everything works fine.

### My version of IE11 on Windows 10 (in older IE11 on Windows 10 there was the same bug)

[image]

### My test page aspx code (I just created an empty web project with this page)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestIEFlicker.aspx.cs" Inherits="IEFlickering.TestIEFlicker" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div style="width: 1000px; height: 300px; background-color: antiquewhite; overflow-x: auto;">
                    <div style="width: 1500px; height: 200px; background-color: aquamarine;">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help, this issue will completely break my corporate application when customers upgrade to Windows 10 and yes they continue to use IE11...

Scrolling in this way is used in many elements of the site, GridView, DetailsViews, etc. It looks very ugly.

Comment: You cannot prevent that. It's an IE thing.

Comment: this is strange, microsoft updatepanel does not work in microsoft browser? is it a bug or feature) maybe something can be done through the App_Browsers configuration?

Comment: The UpdatePanel works fine, it just flickers since the contents are updated.

Comment: but this is not normal, this problem appeared in Windows 10, any click on the UpdatePanels looks ugly..  temporary solution, Im writing a message that the browser is not supported. This is way Microsoft want ?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try to set the [Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback?view=netframework-4.8) to`True`.</s>

Code as below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" CodeBehind="TestIEFlicker.aspx.cs" Inherits="IEFlickering.TestIEFlicker" %>
```

**Edit**:

It is the IE Browser default behavior(bug) or it also might be related the AjaxControlToolkit. There has a workaround, you could use JQuery Ajax to call the web methods (or web API), then update the partial html content, instead of using AjaxControl.

Here are some related articles about using JQuery ajax in Asp.net, you could refer to them:

[Partial page updates with jQuery AJAX](https://philmunro.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/partial-page-updates-with-jquery-ajax/)

[ASP.net AJAX database operations and partial page update](https://forums.asp.net/t/2070631.aspx?ASP%20net%20AJAX%20database%20operations%20and%20partial%20page%20update)

Comment: No it didn’t help. what does the scroll position maintain to do with it?

Comment: @AlexxanderT, When Web pages are posted back to the server, if [the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback?view=netframework-4.8) is set to true, the user is instead returned to the last position on the page. I have checked it with your code in previous, it seems that everything works well, so, I thought perhaps it was a solution, but at present, it's not working, perhaps it is a cache problem. So, please check my edit, you could consider to use JQuery Ajax to update the partial web page.

Comment: I do not use AjaxControlToolkit in this example, and still get flickering..
I also think that this is an IE bug, the question is what solution (using these technologies)